# Can I surpass HTML 'required' field on 'cancel' button press?

Tags: python, html, flask

Complete newbie to web dev so I suspect this might be more of an architectural problem rather than a technical one..

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("templ.html")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'submit' in request.form:
            return str([request.form[val] for val in ['input1', 'input2']])
        if 'cancel' in request.form:
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000')
```

**html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<form action="." method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="input1" required="required">
        <input type="text" name="input2" required="required">
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <button name="submit">Submit</button>
        <button name="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Question:** Can I skip 'required' when cancel button is pressed with this simple design or do I need to employ flask_wtf with wtforms.validators? Could I get a working minimal script with my example code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more efficient way of handling it, but this will work as it places the 'Cancel' button in a separate form.

```
<form action="." method="POST" id ="CancelForm"></form>
<form action="." method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="input1" required="required">
        <input type="text" name="input2" required="required">
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <button name="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="submit" form="CancelForm">Cancel</submit>
    </div>
</form>
```

You may want to give it a different action so you can handle 'cancel' differently

Comment: Thanks, it worked! You might want to edit your answer to add name="CancelForm" and then edit the py script to look for this in request.form? Otherwise it produces an error, unless there is a more conventional way